# Trigonometric Function variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, change-of-variable

I'm currently reading Precalculus with limits and got into chapter 4 of Trigonometry.

I now understood that, an angle $u$ is a real number that correspond to the points $(x,y)$ in the unit circle. So we have now two functions which is $x=\cos u$ and $y=\sin u$ according to the definitions of the right triangle (trigonometric ratios) and unit circle.

My dilemma is, since we have now defined cosine as a function of $x$, so we could call it a function $x=g(u)=\cos u$, when I make a graph, I choose $x$ as vertical axis and $u$ as horizontal axis, because cosine move from right to left in a unit circle. But in the book they choose cosine as $y=\cos x$. But $y$ is already taken as a definition of sine function, $y=f(u)=\sin u$. So how did they interchanged the variables here? This matter is very confusing to me.

Comment: They aren't definitions. In the context of the unit circle, we can write $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta.$ This doesn't mean $x$ is always associated with cosine and $y$ with sine.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about x is not always associated with cosine? As I see, that we are dealing with two functions that simultaneously compute the circle in unit circle?

Comment: In short, it's context specific. For example, if $x+3=4,$ is $x=1$ always, every time you see it in a problem?

Comment: No, it could be any variables as long as we understand the relationships between two algebraic expression. But we are dealing here with geometric properties and we define these ratios in a triangle to be the point (x,y) so I really do no see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigonometric circle is commonly drawn with an horizontal and a vertical axis. Let us call them the cosine and sine axis, respectively.

On the trigonometric circle, a point has the coordinates $(\cos(u), \sin(u))$.

Now if you want to study the cosine and sine as *functions* of an angle, you will plot them in diagrams with the horizontal axis denoting values of $u$ and the vertical axis the value of the cosine or sine.

On the function plot, a point has the coordinates $(u,\cos(u))$ or $(u,\sin(u))$.

---

Notice that I avoided any reference to $x$ and $y$, on purpose.

Now contemplate the following animation (one of the plots is $(\cos (u),u)$, axis exchanged):

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful, with this approach I now understand how they could label x and y to put them on the same graph. Since x, y and angle u are all real numbers, so as long one understood the context.

Answer (score 2):

It is common to plot multiple graphs on the same $x$-$y$ Cartesian plane and label them, say, $y_1=\tan 2x$ and $y_2=\log x$ and $y_3=\cos x.$ As $x$ varies, the three functions each output a $y$ value.

On the other hand, think of that trigonometric unit circle as a parameterised surface rather than as a graph: here, the circle's $x$- and $y$- coordinates are each expressed as a trigonometric function of parameter $\theta.$

In every case, $x, y$ and $\theta$ are just handles. Whether $y=\cos x,\:$ or $y=\cos\theta,\:$ or $y=\sin\theta,\,$ depends entirely on the context.

Comment: Yes I agree! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!

Comment: Yes, but when you say $y = \tan 2x$ **and** $y = \log x$ then does it not follow that $\tan 2x = \log x$?

Comment: @William Abuse of notation. $y_1=\tan 2x$ and $y_2=\log x$ are more careful labellings. The graphs are not typically read as $y=\tan 2x$ **and** $y=\log x,$ unless their intersection(s) are of interest.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Shouldn't you also use different $x$'s, if we are being *really* correct? Like $y_1= \tan x_1$ and $y_2 = \log x_2$? Otherwise it would mean $\tan$ and $\log$ produce $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively, for same $x$?

Comment: @William *Otherwise it would mean tan and log produce $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively, for same x?*  That's exactly the point: $x$ is the independent variable, and $y_1,y_2$ dependent variables. Letting $y_1-f_1(x)$ and $y_1-f_1(x),$ typically $f_1$ and $f_2$ have a common domain.

Comment: Got you! I was going to upvote it anyway if I got my answer, it was helpful. No worries. Sorry to bother you, but I don't understand the comment. "That's exactly the point." Are you agreeing with me? And "letting $y-f_1(x)$ and $y_1 - f_1(x)$"... What does this mean? It sounds incomplete.

Comment: @William Yes, was agreeing. Typo: I'd meant to write "letting $y_1=f_1(x)$ and $y_2=f_2(x)$".

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a little bit tricky the first time you're learning about it. The key issue here is that we're using $y$ to represent two different things.

In the context of the unit circle, when $u$ is your angle, you can write $x = \cos u$ and $y = \sin u$, where $x$ and $y$ refer to points on the unit circle.

So, for example, if you let $u = \frac{\pi}{6}$, then the equations above give us $x = \cos \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $y = \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$. This is telling us that when we move $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis along the unit circle, we get to the point $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Now, when you see $y = \cos x$ or $y = \sin x$, those $x$ and $y$ variables represent something different. They're not referring to the $x$ and $y$-coordinates on the unit circle. Note, in both of these equations, $x$ is the input to the trig function. So, that $x$ represents the same thing as what we were calling $u$ above - the angle we're moving through along the unit circle from the positive $x$-axis.

The $y$ variable in this case represents the output of the trig function, which can be either of the coordinates on the unit circle, $x$ or $y$, depending on whether the trig function is $\cos$ or $\sin$.

So, if our function is $y = \cos x$, the input $x$ is the angle on the unit circle, and the output $y$ is the $x$-coordinate on the unit circle. If our function is $y = \sin x$, the input $x$ is still the angle on the unit circle, and the output $y$ is the $y$-coordinate on the unit circle.

Using the same example as above, if we want to evaluate $y = \cos \frac{\pi}{6}$, we take angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$ on the unit circle, then since it's cosine, we find the $x$-coordinate, which is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and that's the value of the output $y$. If we want to evaluate $y = \sin \frac{\pi}{6}$, we go to the same angle on the unit circle, look at the $y$-coordinate because we're evaluating sine, and get that $y = \frac{1}{2}$ is our output.

Comment: Exactly, it could be tricky because when they picked x and y in the unit circle and not saving them for the last to use them as input and output variables in the graph instead. This is what caused confusing for me because I was so glued into traditional x-y variables. Thanks!