# Does $y = f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ imply $f(x)=g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Okay, this maybe a very dumb question but I can't seem to find a "proper" reason to show why this isn't true.

In some calculus books or notes, I have come across questions where they sometimes begin by saying, "If $y =f(x)$ and $y =g(x)$ are two functions and blah-blah..." I'm curious, is this some "abuse of notation" thing because it should be clear from the context? Because should it not mean that $y =f(x) = g(x)$?.

There is also another context where this is used— While making graphs. The question usually says graph $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ etc.

Surely it is not a substitution, otherwise the two functions would be same. So what does equating (possibly multiple) functions to $y$ mean? Or what is the intended meaning when we say $y =f(x)$ **and** $y =g(x)$?

Comment: It in fact is a slight abuse. Of course , $f(x)$ need not to be the same as $g(x)$ , better would be to omit "$y$" in such formulations.

Comment: @Peter I'm glad someone agrees. I was hesitant to ask this question because I thought it's a pretty dumb question and may be recieved very poorly, here.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: A function is a *deterministic relation* between two quantities. Strictly, we should say, "If $f$ and $g$ are two functions and blah-blah...," and direct students to "graph $f$ and $g$."

---

In the modern formulation, if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, a *function* $f:X \to Y$ is a subset $f \subset X \times Y$ of the Cartesian product satisfying the condition,

> For every $x$ in $X$, there exists a unique $y$ in $Y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$.

If $(x, y) \in f$, we write $y = f(x)$ and say $y$ is the *value* of $f$ at $x$. Loosely, each "input" $x$ to the function $f$ yields a unique "output" $y = f(x)$. The letters $x$ and $y$ are, as noted in your (William's) answer, local dummy variables used to denote elements of the *domain* $X$ and the *codomain* $Y$, respectively.

Particularly, if symbols signify real numbers for definiteness, then
$$
y = x^{2},\qquad
u = s^{2},\qquad
\clubsuit = \heartsuit^{2},\qquad
\text{(etc., etc.)}
$$
have *identical meaning* as notations for *the real squaring function* $\square \mapsto \square^{2}$. (The square may be viewed as a symbol, but better, it may be viewed as a blank in a web form where we can input any numerical expression, and the second square autofills.)

To the edited question, "Let $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$" has meanings that include "Let $f$ and $g$ be functions" and "Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers satisfying $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$." In the second interpretation, we *do* have $f(x) = g(x)$.

---

To get tangentially (as it were) nitpicky, we should also not write $(x^{2})' = 2x$ and the like: $x^{2}$ is not a function but an expression representing a numerical quantity (assuming $x$ is a number), and so does not have a derivative. Instead, we should say,

> "If $f(x) = x^{2}$ for all real $x$, then $f'(x) = 2x$ for all $x$."

Because that's cumbersome, we often fall back on Leibniz notation, $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2}) = 2x$, with the understanding that we Really Mean the implication in quotes.

Comment: Of course, I agree that it can get cumbersome. But I'm being pedantic to understand if I "know" what I'm doing. So if $y= f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, then the correct interpretation is the second one. If I want to mean the first case, then I think it would be better to use the variables that have not already been used to avoid running into the risk of the second interpretation. For example, Let $y_1 = f(x_1)$ and $y_2 = g(x_2)$? Am I correct in saying that? (Again, I know it's not convenient and not the usual practice but still...)

Comment: If I understand your derivative example correctly. Then you mean $(x^2)'=2x$ is incorrect because derivative of a real number $x^2$ should be $0$ not $2x$ but that is a shorthand for "there exists a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ whose derivative is $ \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that maps each real number $x$ to the real number $2x$."

Comment: Or wait do you mean $\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = (x^2)' =2x $ is meaning because $x$ is just a real number? So it'd be like writing $\frac{d}{d5} 5^2 =(5^2)' =(25)' =2 \cdot 5$?

Comment: 1. Arguably, "Let $y = f(x)$ be a function" is already off the rails: The function is $f$. That said, your indexed $x$ and $y$ do make the "local scope" of $x$ and $y$ more explicit. 2. (a) Literally, $(x^2)'$ isn't syntactically meaningful. (b) "There exists a function..." is correct, but recalls Jim Gaffigan's joke "Is anybody here Pope?" There is a unique squaring function; similarly we'd normally ask "Is the Pope here?" 3. Leibniz notation $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$ allows us to deduce (by convention) we're differentiating $x \mapsto x^2$ and evaluating the derivative at $x$.

Comment: I hope some of that helps, but it's possible I'm missing something essential in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question and this is my understanding of what is going on here.

I have always understood the notation $f(x)$ to mean the image of $x$ under $f$ where $x$ is a stand-in for all the elements in the domain of $f$.

Which also, means the $x$ in $f(x)$ and the $x$ in $g(x)$ are different $x$'s because they are a stand-in for different sets of elements. The former $x$ represents any element in the domain of $f$ while the latter $x$ is any element in the codomain of $g$.

Similarly, the $y$ in $y =f(x)$ is stand-in for set of all the elements in the range (not codomain, mind you). So, the $y$ in $y = f(x)$ and the $y$ in $y =g(x)$ are different because they represent different sets of elements. The former $y$ represents any element in the range of $f$ while the latter $y$ is any element in the range of $g$.

That's how I understand it, at least. Thinking of $x$'s and $y$'s as not one particular elements but rather a "stand-in" or a dummy variable that is suppose to represent all the elements in the domain or range respectively, seems like what that notation appears to suggest. I'm curious to see what everyone else thinks of it.

Comment: Related: [How does $y$ equal both $\sin x$ and $\cos x\;?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4340157/21813). P.S. Be careful in claiming that $x$ represents "all elements" or stands for "sets of elements", since $x$ in fact represents a single element in each instance (e.g., "$x=3$ or $7$", rather than "$x=3$ and $7$").

Comment: @ryang Hmm, my terminology was informal. I meant to say that $x$ is an arbitrary element of the domain. So it's definitely the "or" case, not the "and".("and" would never make sense here anyway since 3 cannot be 7)

Comment: @ryang Though I'm not sure if that actually answers my question.

Comment: @ryang I don't think that is actually logically wrong is it? $x^2 = 4 \iff x = 2 \text{ or } x =-2$ but $2$ **and** $-2$ are solutions to that equation. (Since you specifically mentioned "solutions".)

Comment: 1. "$[(x-a)(x-b)=0\iff x=a$ OR $b]$" means that both $a$ AND $b$ are solutions to $(x-a)(x-b)=0.$  2. It is tempting but wrong to write that "$[(x-a)(x-b)=0\iff x=a$ AND $b]$".  Similarly, it is inaccurate to say that $x$ represents multiple elements.  3. None of this is pertinent to your main question.